# commit & push to remote git repo via webhook?

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, github

I want to commit to a git repo from app-engine via webhooks. I cannot install git on appengine. Possible?

I think it should be on GitHub, because they have a browser based text editor which can commit via the browser. E.g. [go here](http://github.com/dustingetz/autodoc/blob/master/todo.txt) and click the `edit` button.

[GitHub api docs](http://github.com/guides/the-github-api) imply read-only operations which doesn't seem to be true.

Also, is this a bad idea? I Know it'll be tough to scale.

Answer (score 1):

The tags say you're using python so this might not be particularly useful, but I do know there's a pure java implementation of git, [JGit](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/), which might work on the app engine. It doesn't look like you can really call java code from python, but you could use a separate instance that you create yourself and use some sort of secure communication channel between this and your app. Assuming there's no undocumented github API that does what you want, that is.